# call a method when tableviewcontroller finish loading data and appear

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to build a table view controller that loads data from a database when it is viewed.

After displaying that data to the user, the table polls the web service for updates, while the data is visible to the user, reloading when the web service responds.

This is the controller:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"in view did appear");
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"menuView" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
}
return self;


}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // make space between the start of the screen and the start of th table
   [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(80,0,0,0)];


   // connect to database
   database = [[connectToDB alloc] init];
   [database setDelegate:self];


   // fill the table from the DB
   [database selectSqlQuere:@"SELECT * FROM ZTASKS"];


   // refresh when table scroll down
   UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
   [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];

 }
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 #pragma mark - Table view data source


 @end
```

How can I have the table remain visible to the user while polling the web service, and update the table when the web service responds?

Comment: Where is your database? On the device? On a server?

Comment: i have DB on booth.. on the device for working offline and another on the server

Comment: What do you mean by "this must be done while database data is visible to the user?" you have already showed the LocalDB data to the user from ViewDidLoad

Comment: yes i already do that

Answer (score 1):

Use [-[UIViewController viewDidAppear:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear%3a)

Comment: i tried but it dose not call automatically i do not know why!!.. and if i decided to call it manually using [self viewDidLoad:YES] i still have the same problem which is where to call this !!

Comment: Don't call this method directly.

Comment: Show your view controller implementation?

Comment: You should call [super viewDidAppear:animated] in your implementation of viewDidAppear. How is this view getting on the screen?

Comment: Which UIKit class are you subclassing? viewDidAppear is a UIViewController method. If you are subclassing UITableView, you can't override UIViewController methods.

Comment: same problem ! nothing changes !!

Comment: @interface tableViewController : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, detailViewControllerDelegate,NSMachPortDelegate , connectToDBDelegate , updateTasksDelegate>

Comment: OK, looks correct. How is the tableview getting onto the screen?

Comment: what do you mean by how ?

Comment: This class, tableViewController, has a view which is a tableview. How are you instantiating tableViewController, and how are you adding the tableview to the view hierarchy? In other words, what is the code you are using to put this onto the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is `[tableView reloadData]`, but your question is very very ambiguous.

Comment: i do not want to do this before reloading the table !! i want to do it after 2 sec of loading the table